# slave dns server, resolv.conf configuration

Tags: domain-name-system

I have two servers (a master and slave) running DNS (bind).  What should the `/etc/resolv.conf` file look like for the master and the slave?  For example should the servers running the DNS have only :

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

or should they refer to the I.P. addresses of each server, as the other servers on the network do :

```
search <mydomain>.co.uk
nameserver 192.168.1.52
nameserver 192.168.1.57
```

Comment: "master and slave" - are your DNS servers authoritative, recursive, or both ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the `listen-on` directive. If the server listens on all interfaces then it does not matter whether it is `127.0.0.1` or the other IP addresses.

Comment: I have `listen-on-v6 { any; };`, so what does that mean?

Comment: It means that it listens on any interface, and therefore 127.0.0.1 is enough. For more details you can read the [BIND9 Administrator's Reference Manual](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.9/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.pdf)